# Only the last image displays from database

Tags: php, sql

I asked this question before but no one could help me unfort. I have images and headings coming from database now the problem is that only one image is displaying(the last image) i need both to display.

here is my revised code

```
$query = "SELECT page_title, page_image FROM pages WHERE id='$page'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
confirm_query($result);
while ($page_fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $page_title = $page_fetch['page_title'];
    $images = $page_fetch['page_image'];

    echo "<div class=\"content \">";
    echo "<h3 class=\"words\"><a href=\"\"> $page_title </a></h3>";
    echo "<a href=\"\"><img src='pics/" . $images . "' width=\"340\" height=\"252\" alt=\"\" /></a>";
    echo "</div>"; //end box

} // close while loop
```

here is my database for pages

```
page_id  id   page_image      page_title
 1       1    ocean.jpg       have a look at the ocean          
 2       1    house.jpg         The  house
```

just some extra info the images must display dynamically , as they coming in from a form to db to this page

Comment: is `id` field is primary key or autoincrement?

Comment: its a foreign key that relates to $page coming in from get request,   both page_titles display but only the last image and i need both to display

Comment: means that `id` field is not unique and table `page` contain multiple recors for `id` field,right? also fire that query in your DB and check how many rows it returns or use mysqli_num_rows.

Comment: @DS9 i did run the  query in the db and it returns the correct data, the id field is unique it is refrenced from the navigation table

Comment: You could add print_r($page_fetch); as a first line in your while-loop to see what is fetched for each row.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 yes it does return both image names just not the actual image  , only one image is actually returned(which is the last image)

Comment: Perhaps one of the images is simply not in the pics folder (another extension or starting uppercase or something).

Comment: @JeroendeJong the image is there in the folder , i just checked again. Also if i remove one image then the first image displays.So both images just wont display at same time

Comment: <img src='pics/ocean.jpg' width='340' height='252' alt='' /><img src='pics/house.jpg' width='340' height='252' alt='' /> Add these two lines, see if it works (if it doesn't, the problem are the images themself in your pics folder)

Comment: @JeroendeJong  both does return when i do that. the thing is i want the images to display dynamically i dont want to add the actual image names to every image tag for php

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 should i loop through the images?  i know i cant user a foreach loop within while loop. i need to display them dynamically

Comment: @LukeSmith: I understand that you want to see them dynamically, but I wanted to know if they showed up that way to debug. Could you show the source of your code (the HTML in your browser if you run the php you made)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are returning your images from your query.

Check the view source page, You will find your error their.

Your returing image name will not match with the image which you got in the folder. (For the second one)